# ActionBarSherlock crashes on SearchView on Android 4.x

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, searchview

If I use:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView searchView = new com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView(Activity_TimetablePager.this);
...
```

System crashes with following log:

```
06-22 18:18:23.384: D/SherlockFragmentActivity(3613): [onCreatePanelMenu] featureId: 0, menu: com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder@af2ca820
06-22 18:18:23.384: D/ActionBarSherlock(3613): [dispatchCreateOptionsMenu] menu: com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder@af2ca820
06-22 18:18:23.384: D/ActionBarSherlock(3613): [callbackCreateOptionsMenu] menu: com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.MenuWrapper@af2cc5c8
06-22 18:18:23.384: D/Watson(3613): [onCreatePanelMenu] featureId: 0, menu: com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.MenuWrapper@af2cc5c8
06-22 18:18:23.384: D/SherlockFragmentActivity(3613): [getSupportMenuInflater]
06-22 18:18:23.384: D/ActionBarSherlock(3613): [getMenuInflater]
06-22 18:18:23.384: D/ActionBarSherlock(3613): [getActionBar]
06-22 18:18:23.384: D/AndroidRuntime(3613): Shutting down VM
06-22 18:18:23.384: W/dalvikvm(3613): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xaecd1908)
06-22 18:18:23.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3613): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-22 18:18:23.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3613): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class <unknown>
06-22 18:18:23.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3613):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
06-22 18:18:23.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3613):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
```

This works fine on Android 2.3, but not on 4.x. I am using ActionBarSherlock 4.3.1, in this case in a viewPager activity. Is this a known issue?

(Currently I have a workaround where I use the default android SearchView in 4.x.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the actionView class in the menu xml resource and getting an (already created) instance of it inside `onCreateOptionsMenu()`?

For example, in your menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/search_item"
          android:title="@string/search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
          android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

Then in your code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_item);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

    ...
}
```

I use this exact pattern in my app and haven't seen any problems on 2.x or 4.x phones.

Comment: Basically I get the same result. In your example code, the searchView = null, while searchItem is still ok. Thus searchItem.getActionView seems to be the problem.

Comment: Your comment lead to another similar question. If I use in the manifest activity definition: android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light", then it works. but if I use styles: <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light"> then it does not. I have no styles defined for v14 (folder values-v14 does not exist).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here was the issue:

I did not use activity specific themes.

I did not define:  in values-v14/styles.xml in the misconception, that if I do not have that file, it will use old styles. Once defined, all works fine.